# Why does ls -R1 & go to foreground

Tags: command-line, background-process

I am trying to let `ls /usr -R1` run in the background (school assignment, I know it sounds like a dumb idea to run ls in the background). I tried running `ls /usr -R1 &` to run it as a job instead of a command but it still runs in foreground. Any idea why and how to stop it?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe ask the instructor for some hints?

Comment: It doesn't. You're just seeing the output, which still goes to the terminal.